# Phonegap and Ionic packaging IOS

Tags: android, ios, ipad, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I have an ionic app that i have uploaded to Phonegap Build. I have added all my IOS certificates and Provisioning profile etc.

I was wondering what the next step was now sothat i can test my App on my IPad? I have done everything other tutorials have said do up to this point but theres nothing explaining how to acctually build the Ios app and put it on my ipad?

I am using Windows and followed this tutorial to get to the point i'm at now:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

Thanks

Comment: are you done with successfully building the app in xcode?

Comment: I'm using windows, i thought phonegap could build my app in the cloud isnt that the point of it?

Comment: not sure of this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zip up your app in the correct structure and upload it to phonegap build. If sucessful you will be able to get the ipa file for the device.

Fastest way to get it onto your ipad would be to just login into build.phonegap on the ipad and click the ipa file and it will install onto the ipad.

Comment: This will do it. The other option is DL the ipa onto a Mac, double click it to add it to iTunes, plug in your iPad and install it from iTunes.